# Provide recursive specifications of the function

Tags: computer-science, recursion

I am given only the successor function

σ(n) = 1+n

And asked to provide recursive specifications of the function

i) add(n,m)=m+n

Is the objective to prove that this is true for all numbers? A bit lost on how to proceed

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The task is probably to give a recursive definition of "add" using only base case(s) and the "σ" operation.